Handle message error in asyncHandler packge
I am trying to test my Api update, when update not exists task return this response
{     
 "msg": "Task Updated Successfully", 
 "data": null 
}

Delete Task Controller
const deleteTask = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const tasks = await taskModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "A Task Deleted Successfully", data: "" });
});

Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
});

how to handle msg to send anthor msg if task not exists

The findByIdAndDelete() will return null if no matching documents were found so can either check for not null like so:
const deleteTask = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   const tasks = await taskModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
   if(!tasks){ //< tasks will be null if no matching document
      return res.status(200).json({ //< early return
         msg: 'No document found'
      });
   }
   res.status(200).json({ msg: "A Task Deleted Successfully", data: "" });
});

or you can use the orFail() method like so:
const deleteTask = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   const tasks = await taskModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id).orFail(() =>{
      return res.status(200).json({ //< early return
         msg: 'No document found'
      });
   })
   res.status(200).json({ msg: "A Task Deleted Successfully", data: "" });
});

